# How do I get bash to follow the same index allocation rules when using variables as compared to raw text values?

Tags: bash

Using an apache CLF log entry and looping through its indices like so:

```
r=(8.8.8.8 - - [06/Sep/2016:12:26:49 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 27127 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko")

for i in ${!r[@]}
do
   echo ${r[$i]}
done
```

Produces the following output.  Thus keeping not only our quoted segments together but also the bracketed segment as well.

```
8.8.8.8
-
-
[06/Sep/2016:12:26:49 -0700]
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
200
27127
-
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

When looping through each line in a log file it's necessary to use a variable for each line.  The following code simulates the use of a variable:

```
line='8.8.8.8 - - [06/Sep/2016:12:26:49 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 27127 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"'
r=($line)

for i in ${!r[@]}
do
   echo ${r[$i]}
done
```

Which ignores the quotations and brackets:

```
8.8.8.8
-
-
[06/Sep/2016:12:26:49
-0700]
"GET
/index.html
HTTP/1.1"
200
27127
"-"
"Mozilla/5.0
(Windows
NT
6.1;
WOW64;
Trident/7.0;
rv:11.0)
like
Gecko"
```

Is it possible to use a variable but keep the index segmentation as seen in the first example?  I have not found any options or syntax which seem to influence this behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to do this with bash. It would be better to write a perl or python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

line='8.8.8.8 - - [06/Sep/2016:12:26:49 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 27127 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"'

# Declare -a means create an array
declare -a 'r=('"$line"')'

for i in ${!r[@]}
do
   echo ${r[$i]}
done
```

**Output**

```
8.8.8.8
-
-
[06/Sep/2016:12:26:49 -0700]
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
200
27127
-
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Have a look at `man bash` and search for `declare` in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section.

[Bash Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)

Comment: While this achieves the result, I fail to find any insight in the bash man page explaining the affects of quoting used in the declare statement also required in order for this to work.

Comment: I agree it is hard to grok.  I believe it has to do with list vs string context.  Have a look at the accepted answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters